# Return document with fitered subdocument

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

My collection looks like as follow:

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("54998c044cf76388944bcb56"),
   "description" : "USP",
   "type" : "FreeInput",
   "localeData" : {
      "Eng" : {
         somedata.....
      },
      "Span" : {
       somedata....
      }
   }
}
```

What I want to do is be able to query for this object but filter the `localeData` objects. For example I want specify "Eng" into my query and then get the following resulting object:

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("54998c044cf76388944bcb56"),
   "description" : "USP",
   "type" : "FreeInput",
   "localeData" : {
      "Eng" : {
          somedata.....
      }
   }
}
```

Is there away to do this without aggregation? if not, then how would I go about it with aggregation? I'm a little shaky on the whole aggregation framework. Also I'm using spring data mongodb.

Comment: You'll need to specify the [`projection`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) parameter when finding the documents.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, this is your answer:

```
var fields = {"description" :1, "type": 1, "localeData.Eng" : 1};
db.test.find( {query} , fields)
```

and for aggregation you could use:

```
db.test.aggregate(
{
    $match : {query}
},
{
    $project : { "description" :1, "type": 1, "localeData.Eng" : 1 }
}
).result
```

Comment: yes that is in essence what I'm looking for. Do you know if there is a way to do this using the spring MongoTemplate without having to resort to the lower level java mongodb driver?